# What Star Trek episodes take place in the Beta Quadrant?

Tags: star-trek

Are there any Star Trek episodes (any series) that take place in the Beta Quadrant?

- TOS, TNG and ENT *mainly* take place in the Alpha Quadrant.
- DS9 *somewhat* takes place in the Gamma Quadrant.
- VOY *mainly* takes place in the Delta Quadrant.

I'm in the middle of DS9 after watching all of VOY and TNG, and I can't recall any episode that mainly took place in the Beta Quadrant or had any key action referencing that quadrant<sup>1</sup>.

Is there any episode that matches the above criteria?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Maybe except for the fact that I heard that the VOY crew was supposed to reach somewhere in the middle of Beta Quadrant, before the series was cut down. But that is not the context in which I'm looking for an answer.</sub>

**EDIT**: *I'm asking about episodes where it is mentioned on-screen, they happen in Beta quadrant*.

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Quadrant) have the answer?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_quadrant_(Star_Trek)) says: Although the Romulans and Klingons are shown by maps as part of the Beta Quadrant, Star Trek: Deep Space Nine did not use this terminology, referring to them as Alpha Quadrant powers. Ronald D. Moore noted that the "Alpha quadrant is firmly planted in the audience's mind as where the Federation, the Klingons, and the Romulans all live so I think we'll stick with that nomenclature".

Comment: Wouldn't the Reunification episodes of TNG, as well as 95% of Nemesis count as taking place in the beta quadrant?

Comment: Well... yes. Seems so!

Comment: “the VOY crew was supposed to reach somewhere in the middle of Beta Quadrant, before the series was cut down” — the series was cut down?

Comment: Wasn't it? Did they reached Earth? Was there any gap between their location in episode one-before-final and final episode? I don't have any sources ready right know, but I've heard like dozen of times, that VOY was cut down, even to actors surprise, because of audience going down and down. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @trejder: the final double episode took them home abruptly by what amounted to a Deus Ex Machina.  That sort of thing does often indicate that the writers had to finish up the story at short notice, but I don't think that's necessarily true in this context - in my judgement it would have taken at least another three or four seasons to finish the story in a more natural way (i.e., with only occasional large jumps homewards) and the ending would have been very anti-climactic.  As for when and how quickly the decision was made, I don't know - that might make a good question!

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for the explanation. Well, all I can say is that, I _did_ hear, that series was cut-off and I _don't_ remember source to credit that statement, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Memory Alpha, the Klingon capital is located in the [Beta Quadrant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Quadrant), as is Vulcan, Andoria, and a number of other well-known planets.

So, as one example, much of [Sins of the Father](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sins_of_the_Father_(episode)) was set on Qo'noS, and hence in the Beta Quadrant.  Similarly, a number of episodes were set on Vulcan, and [The Aenar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Aenar_(episode)) was set on Andoria.

From the fact that the Enterprise NX-01 visited both Andoria and Vulcan at least once, without apparently needing to travel any unusual distance to do so, we can even speculate that most of *Enterprise* was probably set in the Beta Quadrant.  (This is supported by *Star Trek: Star Charts*.)

Support for this interpretation in primary canon is limited.

Answer (score 4):

If we were to rely on the answer for [this question involving quadrants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/can-anyone-explain-the-star-trek-astrography-i-e-quadrants?rq=1) then there have been several episodes and movies taking place in the Beta quadrant.

Star Trek the Undiscovered Country takes place in the Klingon Empire, which is in the Beta Quadrant

Star Trek: Nemesis takes place in the space around Romulus and Remus (as well as the neutral zone), which is also in the Beta quadrant.

There are several episodes of most series (I can't think of any in Voyager off the top of my head) which involve either the Romulan home world, the Klingon home world, or different planets in their respective empires.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of maps for you, both taken from the *[Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts)* book:

> [image]
>   [Source](https://drofdemonology.deviantart.com/art/Star-Trek-Map-1-482984975)

---

> [image]
>   [Source](https://drofdemonology.deviantart.com/art/Star-Trek-Map-2-509478876)

As you can see, the border between Alpha and Beta quadrants passes through the Solar System, effectively splitting the UFP territory in two almost equal parts. It is roughly a situation equivalent to the [Greenwich meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian_(Greenwich))

**So, to answer your question: most of the episodes of TOS, TNG, DS9 and ENT (and now DIS too) take place more or less equally both on the Alpha *and* the Beta quadrants.**

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, because it is too general / too high-level. While asking, I expected an actual list of episodes, which takes place in Beta quadrant (preferably those where the fact that they're happening in Beta quadrant is mentioned on-screen).

Comment: Being them the vast majority and being them in the hundreds, you are asking for something that I doubt anyone is willing to do. I, at least, I'm not really eager to read through the wiki pages of every single ST episode, just to compile a list of items.

Comment: Consider also that questions that explicitly ask for list of items are generally not well accepted here.

Comment: @trejder:   You may have asked for a list of episodes, but that question was based on an incorrect premise -- that the number of episodes would be relatively few.   Since that's not true, this is what you get.   Frankly, this is probably a better answer than the one that's already accepted at this point in time.

Comment: @Sekhemty I don't know about lists of items, but I was pretty sure that asking for list of episodes (with some kind of significance) is on-topic here. I'm pretty sure that I saw a dozen of questions (and answers) like that here. With ST-like tag or any other. No, I disagree, we're not talking about "hundreds" because I'm asking about those episodes where it is mentioned on-screen that they happens in Beta quadrant. Can't believe that there are that many of them.

Comment: @trejder Memory Alpha reports that the last aired DIS episode is the 744 one of all series, and you want an answer that cites all those that explicitly mention on screen the beta quadrant. I am not against this, if someone (or even yourself) want to do it, but I'm not going to do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Beta Quadrant is referenced vaguely throughout the franchise but since no consistent map was ever part of the series bible logic of where things are falls apart and later writers (probably wisely) chose not to call too much attention to it.  That said, the ST Star Charts layout, though not canon, is pretty widely accepted, with Earth near the Alpha-Beta border and Klingons, Romulans, Gorn, etc. being Beta powers with some Alpha territory and being referred to as Alpha powers presumably because they're part of the same political community.  The Federation is Show to have territory in both as well.  How they would function the way Star Charts has it seems problematic, as do episodes that imply closer positions of some factions such as the Klingons and Cardassians, but that all can work once you consider it's a flat map of space and the galaxy is 1,000 light years deep on average, so those empires may have space that sort of wraps over or under the Federation, and all Federation territory may be connected in the same manner.

Comment: This answer would be much better with paragraphs, consistent grammar, punctuation and **evidence to support your points**.

Comment: Earth is not *near* the border between the two quadrants, it (well, Sol) and the center of the galaxy are what *define* the border.