# Identify this Star Trek badge with gamma-like symbol

Tags: star-trek, object-identification, star-trek-insignias

[image]

I have looked and looked on Google images, eBay, Amazon, Star Trek shop, Memory Alpha... There are no references whatsoever to this badge design yet I obtained this commercially available example 20+ years ago.

Which series or stories is it from? What does the symbol mean?

Comment: Do you recall where you obtained this from?

Comment: @Xantec I have a suspicion this could have been something promotional for Star Trek Voyager. Gamma-symbol, Gamma Quadrant... Buy enough VHS tapes, get a badge...

Comment: @Xantec But nothing suggests this symbol was featured in ST Voyager.

Comment: Was it "commercially available" in the sense of being mass-produced, or could it have been the creation of a fan that was sold somewhere?

Comment: Someone on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Treknobabble/comments/r15gwa/what_does_this_symbol_mean_new_to_trek/) says it was a header page for the Star Fleet Technical Manual (originally a fan creation, though it proved popular enough that it was eventually licensed by the Trek IP owners).

Comment: @Hypnosifl It's not been obtained from a fan's forge. There probably never were any in the UK at the time. I never went for Star Trek conventions and such at the time either.
OTOH, would a fan go to the trouble of carefully embossing the symbol, (low-quality) gold plating the badge and filling the "gamma" with some contrasting, hard-wearing black "stuff"?
BTW this is how the badge looks after being stored in a box for 20+ years and wiped with a tissue before posting the photo.

Comment: @Ruutsa - Voyager takes place primarily in the delta quadrant, not gamma.

Comment: @Basya I am a bad Star Trek fan to get that wrong, having binge-watched Voyager recently...

Comment: @Ruutsa - we all make mistakes!  (Even Star Trek fans :-)   )  I wasn't sure myself; had to look it up before I commented!

Comment: Are there any marking on the reverse of the badge?

Comment: @Basya - Takes place in the Delta [*and Beta*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79765/how-was-voyager-still-in-the-delta-quadrant-at-the-end-of-the-series) quadrants, technically speaking.

Answer (score 11):

The symbol (lower-case gamma) Starfleet badge appears in the [*Starfleet Technical Manual*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual), along with a variety of other non-canon badge designs.

To the best of my knowledge, it's never been produced as an *official* badge design which suggests that it was sold to you as a bootleg.

[image]

[image]